# MySQL 5.1.73 - community edition : Where is MySQL configuration file?

Tags: configuration, mysql, configure, oracle-linux

I have installed **MySQL 5.1.73-community edition** in my **Oracle LINUX 5** server. I am able to start / stop and execute MySQL commands. But, I am unable to locate the MySQL installation directory as well as my.cnf file where I can change the configuration as per my requirements.

Comment: Isn't it simply in `/etc`?

Comment: No, its not there.

Comment: Explaining where you've looked would be good so we do not get a pointless sequence of "Isn't it in ___?", "No, I've looked in ____" comments.

Comment: I looked it in (1)/etc/, (2)/var/lib, (3)/opt directories.

Comment: I run the command - `$ find /etc my.cnf`

Comment: Is there any mysql command or variables which displays the path?

Comment: # locate my.cnf                                           this command will help you to fing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#locate my.cnf
```

This command will help you to find the path of the file.

Comment: I got below resultset: `$ locate my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/include/default_my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/federated/my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/ndb/my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl/my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl_ndb/my.cnf`

Comment: Which one is the correct one?

Comment: cp default_my.cnf /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to start / stop and execute MySQL commands.

You should be able to get a clue then from `whereis` + a command name.  This may be just `/usr/bin`, of course, but it also may have added to $PATH instead when installing.

Run `strace whatevercommand | grep '.cnf'` on a command that uses these config files.  This should give the path inside an `open()` call; see `man strace` if you are unfamiliar with this command (in which case, you also may have to install it first from a small distro package).